# Which Instagram API endpoints don't require an access token?

Tags: instagram-api

Some instagram api endpoints are accessible with a client id, e.g.:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&client_id=CLIENT-ID

works, but some endpoints don't, e.g.:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=CLIENT-ID

In the documentation, both endpoints appear to require an access token, listed as:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

and

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Is there any way I can find out which endpoints work with a client id in place of the access token?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that beginning November 17th 2015, the Instagram API has [changed](http://developers.instagram.com/post/133424514006/instagram-platform-update) so that now **all** API requests require an access token.